# AWK comparision after sub

Tags: awk, casting, comparison-operators

I don't understand why AWK doesn't compare properly after using the sub() function.

When I run:

```
echo -e "LG:1000\nLG:3" | awk '{aa=$1; sub("LG:","",aa); if(aa <= 20) {print $0}}'
```

the output is `LG:1000` instead should be `LG:3`.

If I run this command:

```
echo -e "1000\n3" | awk '{aa=$1; sub("LG:","",aa); if(aa <= 20) {print $0}}
```

It works properly the output is `3`.

Comment: `aa` is initially assigned a string value (eg, `LG:1000`) so `aa` will continue to be treated as a string for the rest of the code so the test (`aa <= 20`) is performed with strings and since the string `1000` is 'less than' the string `20` you get `LG:1000`; to have `aa` treated as a numeric you can `+0` to `aa` to trigger a numeric comparison, eg, `aa+0 <= 20`; in your second example `aa` is intiially set to `1000` which could be treated as a string or numeric, so when we get to the test `awk` sees that both sides look numeric (`1000` vs `20`) and opts for a numeric comparison

Comment: An alternative (use `:` as field separator): `echo -e "LG:1000\nLG:3" | awk -F ':' '$2<=20'`